# Coldfusion: Dynamic cfif

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have a db table with five columns (monday to friday). The column value is either 1 (working day) or 0 (not a working day). I am trying to create a `cfif` statement that only executes when the actual day of the `cfloop` is a working day. I think I need a dynamic if statement, or is there another way to solve my problem?

I know the following code doesn't work, but (I hope) it shows what I want. Thanks for your help

```
    <cfset ifstatement = "">
    <cfif realholidays.Montag is 0>
        <cfset ifstatement = " AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 2">
    </cfif>
    <cfif realholidays.Dienstag is 0>
        <cfset ifstatement = " AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 3">
    </cfif>
    <cfif realholidays.Mittwoch is 0>
        <cfset ifstatement = " AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 4">
    </cfif>
    <cfif realholidays.Donnerstag is 0>
        <cfset ifstatement = " AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 5">
    </cfif>
    <cfif realholidays.Freitag is 0>
        <cfset ifstatement = " AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 6">
    </cfif>

    <cfif #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 1#ifstatement#>...</cfif>

    The result should be:

    <cfif #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 1 AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 3  AND #DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is not 5></cfif>
```

Comment: Try to explain what you're trying to achieve. Don't just through a code and expect people to fix it.

Comment: The cfif-statement should only be executed when the actual day of an cfloop is a working day. if it's a working day you can see in the db-table:. There are five columns (monday to friday) where the vaule ist 1 (working day) or 0 (not a working day).

Comment: Please update your answer and explain what help you're looking for.

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Vermeer - I strongly suspect the db table structure is not ideal, and could be simplified. However, since we cannot see your db, it is difficult for anyone to offer advice. Can you please edit your question to a) include the [table DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language#CREATE_TABLE_statement), b) explain the source and purpose of `holidaydatum`, and c) how they both relate to your ultimate goal?

Comment: Okay, my ultimate goal is to calculate the remaining holiday of an employee. i have an db table with the national holidays and one db-table with the employee data. i loop throug the year and look on every day: Has the employee vacations on this day? If yes, i must substract one day from his holiday quota - except it's an national holiday, it's weekend or the certain user doesn't work on this day (p.e. if the user doesn't have a 5-days-week)

Comment: employees:
  `ID`
  `Employee`
  `Holidayquota`
  `Montag`
  `Dienstag`,
  `Mittwoch` ,
  `Donnerstag`,
  `Freitag`
  
  
Holidays
  `Start` date
  `End` date
  `EmployeeID`

  
Nationalholidays:
  `Day` date

Comment: Seems like you are missing a table (or two). If `employees` only contains the *expected* work schedule each week, the actual holiday/vacation dates an employee has taken thus far should be stored somewhere else. Then calculating the days remaining
could be done with a simple query. Though you may want to normalize the Monday-Friday columns too. Which DBMS (sql server, mysql, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic if statement rarely sounds like it will fix any problem that can't be achieved in a 'cleaner' and more readable way.

You might want to look into using functions ([cffunction](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffunction.html)). As your example is difficult to follow, I can only offer up some pseudo code to help you on your way.

```
<cffunction name="isHoliday">
    <cfargument name="realholidaysValue" type="string" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="holidaydatum" type="string" required="false" default="" />
</cffunction>

<cfif isHoliday(realholidays, 1)></cfif>
```

Something else you might need to consider as your example has multiple conditions is a lookup using a [cfstruct](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7fe4.html) or a [cfswitch](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfswitch.html):

```
<cfswitch expression="#DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)#"> 
    <cfcase value="1">
        ... do something, return etc
    </cfcase>
</cfswitch>

<cfset lookup.Donnerstag="5" />
<cfset lookup.Mittwoch="4" />
```

Try and break your problem down into smaller, clearer routines then build them back up to solve your overall problem - you'll thank yourself when you come back to it in 6 months time.

Comment: Your solutions looks good! I will try it and i will tell if it works for me

Comment: My solution: It looks dirty, but it works...

<cfif (not (#DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is 2 AND realholidays.Montag is 0)) AND (not (#DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is 3 AND realholidays.Dienstag is 0)) AND (not (#DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is 4 AND realholidays.Mittwoch is 0)) AND (not (#DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is 5 AND realholidays.Donnerstag is 0)) AND (not (#DayOfWeek(holidaydatum)# is 6 AND realholidays.Freitag is 0))>

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach as it pertains to dynamically generating code sounds good in theory, but has a problem in practice.  Consider this simple example of dynamically created CF code.

```
<cfif condition1>
<cfset dynamicCode = "
   <cfif condition2>
   code for condition2 being true
   <cfelse>
   code for condition2 being false
   </cfif>">

<cfelse>
<cfset dynamicCode = "some different programing code than above">
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
#dynamicCode#
</cfoutput>
```

One might think that this will cause dynamicCode to be executed, but it won't.  In fact, it won't even complile.  It's simply a string variable that will be displayed.

If you want it to execute, you have to:

1. create the code as shown above
2. write that code to a .cfm file.  You can use `cffile` for this.
3. include that file with a `cfinclude` tag.

This, of course is all general.  Based on your question, I see no need for you to create dynamic code as all, as you have already found out.